# add element into the same div as primary menu LI in genesis_do_nav?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress-theming

I am just starting out and have limited PHP knowledge, but I am trying to learn as fast as I can. I am working with the Genesis framework and designing a site for someone. I moved my navigation to the top of the page using remove_action & add_action. So now the genesis_do_nav loads on the genesis_header hook. But I would like to have my logo inline with the navigation bar at the top and centered. Should I add that element to the genesis_do_nav? And how would I go about that? I found the function in the menu.php so I started tinkering with it before I move it to a newly named function in my child theme, but whatever I do to the code it only seems to add it before or after the navigation and appears as an block element, I would prefer if I could get it in the same div with the primary menu li. Like I said my knowledge of PHP is limited. Please help.

```
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_nav' );

function genesis_do_nav() {

//* Do nothing if menu not supported
if ( ! genesis_nav_menu_supported( 'primary' ) )
    return;

//* If menu is assigned to theme location, output
if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) {

    $class = 'menu genesis-nav-menu menu-primary';
    if ( genesis_superfish_enabled() )
        $class .= ' js-superfish';

    $args = array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'container'      => '',
        'menu_class'     => $class,
        'echo'           => 0,
    );

    $nav = wp_nav_menu( $args );

    //* Do nothing if there is nothing to show
    if ( ! $nav )
        return;

    $nav_markup_open = genesis_markup( array(
        'html5'   => '<nav %s>',
        'xhtml'   => '<div id="nav">',
        'context' => 'nav-primary',
        'echo'    => false,
    ) );
    $nav_markup_open .= genesis_structural_wrap( 'menu-primary', 'open', 0 );
    $nav_markup_close  = genesis_structural_wrap( 'menu-primary', 'close', 0 );
    $nav_markup_close .= genesis_html5() ? '</nav>' : '</div>' ;
    $nav_output = $nav_markup_open . $nav . $nav_markup_close;
    echo apply_filters( 'genesis_do_nav', $nav_output, $nav, $args);
   }
}
```

I would like it to end up inline with the primary menu LI

```
        echo apply_filters( 'genesis_do_nav', $nav_output, $nav, $args, HTML ELEMENTS HERE?);
```

Comment: share code that i know how i handle

Comment: I handled it my own way. I just absolutely positioned the element below it into place.

Comment: do u solve ur own problem?